# Ant execution different depending on svn export

Tags: java, svn, jar, ant, build.xml

I have an `ant build.xml` script. In order to run my application, it requires external libraries.

I am able to successfully run  `ant clean jar`  in the command prompt, and in the  `-do-jar-copylibs`  function the libraries are copied, the jar is built, and the jar can be ran by `java -jar jarfile.jar` This is ran on code that I have extracted manually from svn.

The issue comes when I use a script to `svn export` the code and build file from svn to the C:/temp directory and then run  `ant clean jar`  the build of the application happens in  `-do-jar-jar`  instead of the  `-do-jar-copylibs` . It doesn't copy all the libraries into the dist folder, it just builds the jar and tells me that the jar can be ran using `java -jar "lots/of/libraries.jar" jarfile.jar mainclass`

Does this have to do with permissions? I cannot find any answers to how to fix this. Maybe there is a way to set permissions of `svn export`

Any help is appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

The `-do-jar-copylibs` function relies on the `libs.CopyLibs.classpath` property being set, if it is set correctly, the `condition property="do.mkdist"` will result in true, which triggers the `-do-jar-copylibs` funciton. If the `condition property="do.mkdist"` is false, then the `-do-jar-jar` will run instead.

This classpath being set has to do with the `nbproject/private.properties` file. If I added the private directory to my svn export, the build packaged correctly. Another workaround is to define the classpath in your project.properties file.